# Angular Component Library

Tags: angular, web, angular-material, ng-bootstrap

Im currently developing a Angular website and I would like to add a sidebar and a dropdown menu. 
i have looked at Angular Material and ng Bootstrap. 
but material only provides the sidebar and bootstrap only the dropdown.

are there any free libraries which provide both or are there any other approaches to this issue.

Glad for your help

Comment: Material provides both. You can use [**Menu (mat-menu)**](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview)  **OR**  [**Select (mat-select)**](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)

Comment: @Faisal thanks alot, i was looking in the components for a dropdown